# "enter network password" changing shared folders permissions remotely in windows

Tags: windows, permissions, remote

I have shared folders on a computer (say computer x) on a local network. I sign in on another computer (say computer y) with an administrator account on computer y which is the owner of those shared folders and has full permissions over them. When I try to change those folders' permissions a dialog box appears with the title "Network Password". I have tried any combinations of users and passwords I know but I cannot get passed this dialog box and consequently am unable to alter permissions. How can I solve this problem? I appreciate any help.

thank you in advance

Comment: Hi - when you are working on computer y and are asked for the network password accessing computer x, try typing in the form domain\accountname & password - substitute domain with the actual name of computer x.

Answer (score 0):

How do you access the files on your remote computer?

Do access it via admin share (c$) or did you actually share the folder (*right klick* --> *properties* --> *sharing*)?

Do you have the the right permissions on the file system (NTFS) as well as on the network share? Because those differ.

You can read something about it [here.](https://serverfault.com/a/788766/362661)

Hope that helps.

Comment: I shared the folders using the second approach you said, i.e. by opening the folders' properties and applying the necessary changes with full control permissions. Yes the permissions are everywhere full. the problem still persists!  :(

Comment: Sounds odd. Maybe in following thread is some useful information for you: http://serverfault.com/q/789167/362661